# Token unkown error in stored procedure when updating on external database

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-update, firebird

```
create or alter procedure UPDATECAS (
VNEWSTOCK double precision,
as
declare variable LCCOMANDO2 varchar(256);
begin
  LCCOMANDO2 = 'update CAS
          set STOCK = STOCK-' || :VNEWSTOCK || '';

  for execute statement LCCOMANDO2 on external 'C:\DB\DB.GDB' as
  user 'SYSDBA' password 'masterkey'
  suspend;
end
```

I am using Firebird and I want to create a stored procedure to do an update in another database and I do not understand what I am missing because when compiling it gives me the following error:

> can't format message 13:896 -- message file C:\WINDOWS\firebird.msg not found.
> Dynamic SQL Error.
> SQL error code = -104.
> Token unknown.
> suspend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code 13:896 is usually shown as error code 336397184, which translates to message "Invalid token". (as an aside: The *"can't format message"* error is an indication that you're using a `fbclient.dll` that can't find the `firebird.msg` file with error messages, or you're using an older version that doesn't contain the specific message)

In this specific case, the problem is that you made a syntax error: your statement is missing the word `DO`, as shown in [`FOR EXECUTE STATEMENT`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-forexec) in the Firebird 2.5 Language Reference. As a result, the Firebird parser finds a `SUSPEND` in a position it doesn't expect it (it either expects `DO`, or another token from the `FOR EXECUTE STATEMENT` syntax). The - obvious, but incorrect - fix would be:

```sql
for execute statement LCCOMANDO2 on external 'C:\DB\DB.GDB' as
  user 'SYSDBA' password 'masterkey' do
begin
  suspend;
end
```

Note: enclosing the `suspend;` in `begin` ... `end` is not necessary, but in my opinion it improves readability.

This would solve the immediate problem, but will then result in another error, because the `FOR EXECUTE STATEMENT` is intended to execute statements that produce a result set, and `UPDATE` does not produce a result set.

Instead, you need to use `EXECUTE STATEMENT` without `FOR`. I would also highly recommend that you appropriately parameterize your update statement, instead of concatenating values into the query string. Given your stored procedure doesn't produce any data (it has no `RETURNS` clause), use of the `SUSPEND` clause is also inappropriate.

The final code should be something like:

```sql
create or alter procedure UPDATECAS (VNEWSTOCK double precision)
as
begin
  execute statement ('update CAS set STOCK = STOCK - :newstock') (newstock = VNEWSTOCK) 
    on external 'C:\DB\DB.GDB' as user 'SYSDBA' password 'masterkey';
end
```

Be aware though, that using double precision for something that is stock doesn't seem appropriate. Usually stock is discrete units, so `INTEGER` or `BIGINT` would be more appropriate, or if you need decimal values, the exactness of `DECIMAL` (or `NUMERIC`) is probably better than the inexactness of `DOUBLE PRECISION`.